# Change image with keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys I have image grid in my portfolio website. They are modal and when I click the image it pops up in front of the site, but I can't figure out how to make them change with the keyboard arrows. This is link to the page http://valerikarageorgiev.com/Photography/index.html , and this is the javascript:

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a 
caption
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
imgs[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = e.target.src;
captionText.innerHTML = e.target.alt;
});
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
modal.style.display = "none";
}

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;

// 27 is the ESC key
if(e.keyCode === 27) modal.style.display = "none";
};
</script>
```

Comment: You already know how to do this: `modalImg.src = e.target.src;`, you have an array of images, and you know how to catch keyinput, so what stops you from just implementing it? Keep a counter that represents the index of the current picture that is shown and increase or decrease it based on the arrow keys, and replace the `src` value.

Comment: the problem is that I have almost zero knowledge at javascript so I found this code оnline and I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434028/image-change-on-pressing-keyup-and-keydown/50434320#50434320

Comment: this doesn't help me or I can't make it work...

Comment: @ВалериК.ah well then I'd recommend starting to learn javascript, we are not here to write code for you. If you run into a problem we're happy to help. This is not a forum for tutorials however.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following event listener and check for the RightArrow/LeftArrow code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
    if(ev.keyCode === 37){
    //Left arrow
    }
    else if(ev.keyCode === 39){
    //Right arrow
    }
});
```

Then you can find your popup component by id and it should have next/previous functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `left`, `righ`t and `es`c key are working as it supposed to be. But i could not figure out what event should be displayed. Because mostly i use function and array store images. You can try this code as it shows `alert` when `left` and `right` key are pressed so key events are working. Just add the necessary displaying which needed to be displayed on that event and it will work.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

html, body  {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 padding:0px; 
 margin:0px;
 background-color:white;
 
}

body {
 
 overflow-x:hidden;
}



@font-face {
    font-family:futuraat;
 src:url( ../content/font/FuturaPTLight.otf); }
 
@font-face {
    font-family:futuraa;
    src:url(  ../content/font/FuturaPTBook.otf);
} 

@font-face {
    font-family:mood;
    src:url( CONTENT/font/CODE-Light.otf);
} 

#header {
 
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
 width:100%;
 height:52px;
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0px;
 z-index:9100;
 
}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 9999; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow:hidden; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
 font-family:futuraa;
 font-size:22px;
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
 margin-top:-4%;
 z-index:9999;
 
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
 
}

.myImg {
 
 cursor:pointer;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
 
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
 boredr:3px white solid;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


#header ul {
 list-style: none; 
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 width:100%; 
 position:relative;
 right:5%;
 
 
}


#aaaaa{
 
 width:100%;
 
}


#header li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left:1px;
 margin-top:-3px; 
 float:right;
 margin:12px 10px 0px 25px;
 
}
.menua {  

 color:rgb(0,0,0);
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:23px;
 font-family:futuraat;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 opacity:0.5;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
 
}

.menua:hover {
 

 color:rgb(0,0,0);
 opacity:0.9;
}



#nagore {
 position:fixed;
 display:none;
 z-index:9999;
 top:50%;
 right:10px;
 width:40px;
 opacity: .90;
   animation: pulse 1.2s linear alternate infinite;
 border:1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1) solid;
 border-radius:50px;
 padding:4px;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}


#logo1 {
 width:190px;
 height:auto;
 position:absolute; 
   margin: auto; 
 margin-left:-115px; 
 top:115px;
 left:50%;
 z-index:1; 
}


#logooo {
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 z-index:9000;
 width:100%;
 
 height:100%;
}

#logo {
 position:absolute;
 height:35px;
 top:11px;
 left:5%;
 opacity:0.5;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
}

#logo:hover {
 position:absolute;
 opacity:0.7;
}

#logo5 {
 
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:10%;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-125px;
 width:250px;
 z-index:1;
 opacity:.9;
 
}

#menu-icon {
 background:url( content/images/menu-icon-11.png); 
 background-size:100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 display:none; 
 height:30px;
 width:40px;
 margin:14px 14px 0px 0px; 
 opacity:0.8;
 
}

.categories {
 
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
}

.categories a {
 
 text-decoration:none;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.categories a:hover {
 
 text-decoration:none;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

#categor {
 position:relative;
 color:black;
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 top:100px;
 font-family:futuraat;
 font-weight:300;
 font-size:34px;
}

#categor2 {
 position:relative;
 color:black;
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 top:180px;
 font-family:futuraat;
 font-size:34px;
 padding-top:60px;
}

#categor3 {
 position:relative;
 color:black;
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 top:-80px;
 font-family:futuraat;
 font-size:34px;
 padding-top:60px;
 
}

#categor1 {
 position:relative;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 top:120px;
 font-family:futuraat;
 font-size:24px;
}

#snimki {
 position:relative;
 margin-top:190px;
 width:90%;
 left:5%;
 padding-bottom:150px;
}

#ani {
 position:relative;
 width:80%;
 left:10%;
}

#video-background {

  position: relative;
 top:-70px;
 left:5%;
 width: 90%; 
 box-shadow: 0px -5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
 z-index:50;
 margin:30px 0px;
}




@media only screen and (max-width:640px){
 #header {
  position:fixed;
 }
 
 
 #menu-icon {
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  top:6px;
  right:8px
 }
 
 .zooom {
  visibility:hidden;
 }
 
 h2 {
  display:block;
  
 }
 #header ul, nav:active ul {
  
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 right:0px;
 top:52px;
 width:100%; 
 z-index:3000;
 
 
 }
 
 #header:hover ul {
  display: block;
   }
 
 #header li {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px 0;
  margin: 0;  
 }
 .menua{
 color:white; 
  
 }
}

.mmm {
}

.row img {
 
 opacity:1
}

.row img:hover {
 
 opacity:0.8;
}










* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 32px;
 opacity:0;
}

.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    -ms-flex: 33.3333%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 33.3333%;
    max-width: 33.3333%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 50%;
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 100%;
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-110185463-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-110185463-1');
</script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="../content/images/logoISO.ico" />
<meta name="description" content="Valeri Karageorgiev loves design, photography and snowboarding"/>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Photograhy</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="../content/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   
   var target = this.hash;
   var $target = $(target);
   
   $('html, body').animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
   }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
   });
  });
 });
 </script>
 
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <a href="../index.html" ><img src="../content/images/home.png" id="logo"></a>  
  <nav>   
   <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
   <ul id="opa">
    <li><a href="../Contact/index.php" id="kon" class="menua">Contact</a></li>
    
    <li><a href="../Story/index.html" id="pro" class="menua">Story</a></li>
       
   </ul>   
  </nav>       
 </div>
 
<a href="#categor"><img src="../content/images/strelka.png" id="nagore"></a>
 
<div class="categories">

<h1 id="categor">Photography</h1> 
 

 
 <div class="header" >
  <h1>Responsive Image Grid</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
</div>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://valerikarageorgiev.com/content/images/Photography/1.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" alt="Жоркатааа">
    <img src="http://valerikarageorgiev.com/content/images/Photography/2.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/3.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/4.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/5.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/6.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/7.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/8.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/9.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/10.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/11.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
   <img src="../content/images/Photography/33.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/34.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/35.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/36.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
  </div>
 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/12.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" alt="Жоркатааа">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/22.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/13.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/14.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/15.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/16.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/17.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/18.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/19.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/20.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/21.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
   <img src="../content/images/Photography/37.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/38.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/39.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/40.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
     <img src="../content/images/Photography/32.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" alt="Жоркатааа">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/45.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/23.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/24.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/25.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/26.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg">
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/27.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/28.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/29.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/30.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/31.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
   <img src="../content/images/Photography/41.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/42.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/43.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
    <img src="../content/images/Photography/44.jpg" style="width:100%" class="myImg" >
  </div>
  
 
</div> 
 </div> 
 
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
 
 
<script>
   $(window).scroll(function() {
  var pxFromBottom = 6300;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - pxFromBottom) {
   $('#nagore').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
   $('#nagore').fadeOut('slow')
   }
  }); 
 </script>
 
 
 <script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = e.target.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = e.target.alt;
    });
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
   
}
  
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
   
  e = e || window.event;

  if(e.keyCode== 37)   {

    alert('left key')


  }
  if(e.keyCode== 39)   {

    alert('right key')


  }
  
    // 27 is the ESC key
    if(e.keyCode === 27) modal.style.display = "none";
};


</script>
 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working. And also when I remove the command for the escape key and put your code the ESC key stopped to work.

Comment: can you please send me code of html also. so i can check

Comment: I put it as a comment

Comment: I have edited comment copy the code and use https://codepen.io/ to test as its showing some error in snippet

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="column">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/1.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg" alt="Жоркатааа">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/2.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/3.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/4.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">
</div>

<div class="column">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/12.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg" alt="Жоркатааа">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/22.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/13.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/14.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">

</div>  
<div class="column">
 <img src="../content/images/Photography/32.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg" alt="Жоркатааа">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/45.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/23.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">
<img src="../content/images/Photography/24.jpg" style="width:100%" 
class="myImg">    
</div>  
</div>  
</div>  

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<img class="modal-content" id="img01">
<div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a 
caption
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
imgs[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = e.target.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = e.target.alt;
});
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
modal.style.display = "none";
}

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;

// 27 is the ESC key
if(e.keyCode === 27) modal.style.display = "none";
};
</script>
```